# Burns or Burn's Nurse

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing a direct quote so I cannot change the sentence around.

The speaker consistently refers to the hospital "burns nurse", as in a nurse that takes care of patients with burns.

I believe I would just leave it as it is, *burns nurse*. But I just wanted to make sure it is not *burn's*.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the possessive *'s*.

So you are correct with leaving *"burns nurse*" as *the nurse of burns*.

Answer (score 1):

"Burns nurse" is correct.  "Burns" is used to describe the nurse's specialty.

An apostrophe would inappropriately indicate possession, i.e., "of or belonging to the burn."

Answer (score 0):

As Dan says, you're correct. It's a nurse in charge of burns not a nurse belonging to one burn. (Although there would be a subtle trap in a Burns Night Nurse.....)